# Different HTML folding for notepad++

Tags: notepad++, html, code-folding

My question is pretty straightforward.

Lets say this is my HTML in notepad++

```
<div id="ff">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Now when I fold this lines, it appears like that

```
<div id="ff">
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but I want to fold it like that

```
<div id="ff">
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
</div>
```

Is it possible with notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

### Sort of...

If you can temporarily live without other HTML syntax features, you can switch language from **HTML** to **Python** or **Visual Basic**.

They have indentation-based folding which will do exactly what you expect:

[image]